# 'No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common.by'' Error in Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting this output in Sublime Text when trying to run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
PATH = "C:/Users/josh.bailey/Documents/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get ("https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/")
time.sleep(5)
search = driver.find_element_by_id("wizard_vehicle_enquiry_capture_vrn_vrn")
search.send_keys("*REDACTED*")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
main = driver.find_element_by_class("reg-mark-sm")
print(main.text)
driver.quit()
```

This is pretty basic code, I'm just trying something out to make a business process a lot easier when inputting vehicle details into our database. The code isn't finished yet, but I'm only stuck because of this error printout:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\josh.bailey\Documents\Test3.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver

  File "C:\Users\josh.bailey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
    packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa

  File "C:\Users\josh.bailey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
    packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 27, in 
    <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as 
    RemoteWebDriver
  
  File "C:\Users\josh.bailey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
    packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 41, in 
    <module>
    from .shadowroot import ShadowRoot

  File "C:\Users\josh.bailey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
    packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\shadowroot.py", line 21, in 
    <module>
    from ..common.by import By

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common.by'
[Finished in 195ms]
```

There's definitely a by.py file in selenium\webdriver\common directory, just as there is a keys.py file. I've opened the by.py file and it appears to have all the content inside it should have. is there something I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please correct the line it is **"find_element_by_class_name"**

```
main = driver.find_element_by_class("reg-mark-sm")

to 

main = driver.find_element_by_class_name("reg-mark-sm")
```

here is the complete code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:/Users/josh.bailey/Documents/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get ("https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/")
time.sleep(5)
search = driver.find_element_by_id("wizard_vehicle_enquiry_capture_vrn_vrn")
search.send_keys("*REDACTED*")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
main = driver.find_element_by_class_name("reg-mark-sm")
print(main.text)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve **No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common.by'**, you can try you installing the webdriver-manager module.

```
# ↓ Python 2
pip install webdriver-manager

# ↓ Python 3
pip3 install webdriver-manager
```

Sample usage of the module: **selenium.webdriver.common.by**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import by
...
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'foo')
```